# How to group distinct comma separated values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have main_mappings table with data like this:

```
mid  sid
1    1,2,3
1    2,4
3    1
4    2
4    5,9
```

I want to get this:

```
mid  sids
1    1,2,3,4
3    1
4    2,5,9
```

I tried this:

```
select mid, listagg(sid, ',') within group   (order by sid)
from main_mappings group by mid;
```

but it gave me this:

```
1    1,2,3,2,4
3    1
4    2,5,9
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing values as comma-delimited lists.

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your table, so that each value is stored in different row.
For this situation, you can make use of nested tables to generate rows for each csv value, find distinct rows and then `listagg` on it.

```
select mid, listagg(sid, ',') within group(order by sid) sids
from (
select distinct m.mid, x.column_value sid
from main_mappings m,
table(
  cast (
    multiset(
      select regexp_substr(m.sid,'[^,]+',1,level)
      from dual
      connect by level <= regexp_count(m.sid,',') + 1
    )
  as sys.odcinumberlist)
)x )
group by mid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution.

```
SELECT listagg(ra,',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ra)
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT (REGEXP_SUBSTR('02,02,02,02,02,03,04,03', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) )ra
        FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('02,02,02,02,02,03,04,03', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
)
```